# Generic extension method is slower than non-generic extension method

Tags: c#, performance, generics, extension-methods

I wrote an extension method for Lists that finds the index of a given value (or the next bigger value) in a sorted list.

```
public static int LinearSearch(this List<int> list, int startIndex, int value)
{
    for (int i = startIndex; i < list.Count; i++)
        if (list[i].CompareTo(value) >= 0)
            return i;

    return -1;
}

public static int LinearSearch<T>(this List<T> list, int startIndex, T value) where T : IComparable
{
    for (int i = startIndex; i < list.Count; i++)
        if (list[i].CompareTo(value) >= 0)
            return i;

    return -1;
}
```

As you see I wrote it once generic an once specifically for integers. If I comment out the int-specific version my code runs approximately much slower as if I prove both (given I work on int-lists).

How can I make the generic version as fast as the non-generic one? I don't want to copy and paste my code to get that performance for ints and longs.

The test runs 10,000,000 random queries on a sorted list of 1,000 integers.

```
LinearSearch took 9823 ms // generic
LinearSearch took 1553 ms // int-specific
```

## Test-code for performance-measurements

```
class Program
{
    const int count = 1000;
    const int runs = 10_000_000;
    static List<int> list = new List<int>();
    static List<int> queries = new List<int>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MeasureRuntime(CreateTestData);
        MeasureRuntime(LinearSearch);
    }

    private static void LinearSearch()
    {
        foreach (int query in queries)
            list.LinearSearch(query);
    }

    private static void CreateTestData()
    {
        Random random = new Random(0);
        list.Add(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) list.Add(list[list.Count - 1] + random.Next(0, 10));
        for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++) queries.Add(random.Next(0, list.Count - 1));
    }

    private static void MeasureRuntime(Action action)
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        action();
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"{action.GetMethodInfo().Name} took {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
    }
}
```

Comment: Half as fast on what input?

Comment: Show us how you're doing your benchmark.  I have a feeling the one you run *first* will always be "slower".

Comment: `IComparable` will cause boxing when calling `CompareTo`, use `where T : IComparable<T>`.

Comment: Did you run without the debugger attached ?

Comment: @Lee I was under the impression that one of the point of generics was to avoid boxing/unboxing in such casses

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, it is, which is why Lee suggested that. Otherwise, it uses IComparable instead of IComparable<T> causing the boxing/unboxing: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir - It is, which is why the constraint on `LinearSearch<T>` should be `where T : IComparable<T>` instead of the non-generic `IComparer` interface.

Comment: @Lee yes, you are right , just did the test with IComparable<T> there is no perf diff now. I would make an answer of that comment :)

Comment: That did the trick! If I use IComparable<T> instead of IComparable it runs as fast as the specific version. :-)

Comment: @user2033412 Please post as solution then, free rep :D

Comment: Yep. [IComparable.CompareTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto(v=vs.110).aspx) takes an `object` as its parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that I used the non-generic version `IComparable` instead of `IComparable<T>` which caused a performance-degregation. Now, using `IComparable<T>` the generic version runs as fast as the type-specific one.

```
public static int LinearSearch<T>(this List<T> list, int startIndex, T value) 
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    for (int i = startIndex; i < list.Count; i++)
        if (list[i].CompareTo(value) >= 0)
            return i;

    return -1;
}
```